# Javascript open a windows after a delay then close it after another delay

Tags: javascript, html

I try to create a JavaScript function that, when user clicks on a button, opens a new tab after a small timeframe then wait one second and close it.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("myLink");
btn.onclick = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var win = window.open(
        "http://www.stackoverflow.com", 
        "The new Link")
    },500);
    setTimeout(function(){
            win.close();
        if (win.closed) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            winClosed();
            alert("'The new Link' window closed !");
        }
    }, 2500);
}
```

But the second `setTimeout` function is not executed. When I remove one of the two `setTimeout` function, the other one works fine, but I need to have the two running.

Edit: changed timeout values to take into account @lk77 comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues in your code.

1. you are initializing the variable `win` in the first timeout, meaning it will not be available in the second timeout. You might [want to read about closure & scoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) in javascript.
2. Your first timeout has a delay of `1500` ms and the second one `500`, meaning that the second timeout fires before the first one.

This should be working:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("myLink");
btn.onclick = function() {
    var win = null; // initialize here so it is available in both timeouts
    setTimeout(function() {
        win = window.open( // set the value here
        "http://www.stackoverflow.com", 
        "The new Link")
    },500); // this should fire first
    setTimeout(function(){
            win.close();
        if (win.closed) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            winClosed();
            alert("'The new Link' window closed !");
        }
    }, 1500); // this should fire second
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second `setTimout`'s callback will gets executed before the first one as you did. On way to solve this issue is to add the second `setTimeout` inside the first one, like so:

```
let btn = document.getElementById("myLink");
btn.onclick = function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    let win = window.open("http://www.stackoverflow.com", "The new Link");
    let timer = setTimeout(function () {
      win.close();
      if (win.closed) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        //winClosed();
        //alert("'The new Link' window closed !");
      }
    }, 1000);
  }, 500);
};
```